# Is it possible to receive a webhook to my app before Heroku Postgres goes read-only?

Tags: heroku-postgres

I have an application that handles some data in memory.
I'd like to close the operations and persist the data into DB so that a reboot wouldn't destroy it.

My app opens some resources in various third parties and it I'd like to close them. After that the app can happily go down and wait until it reboots.

What I found is that Heroku has various webhooks for application deployment state changes and so on. But I couldn't find a way to trigger a webhook before the DB becomes read only.

I would like to have a webhook that tells me that "in 5 minutes PostgreSQL will become read only". And then later the app can reboot and for now it doesn't matter.

Also I couldn't find any info if this is even possible. I couldn't find an email for support as well.
Is there a way to do it? Is it even possible?

(I have an Event-Sourced app that saves event data into DB but persists the data in-memory as it runs. So I don't want to continuously bash all of my state into the DB).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some amount of confusion with regards to your understanding about the various parts of dyno and database uptime on Heroku.

Firstly, a database going into read-only mode is a very rare event usually associated with a critical failure. Based on what behavior you're seeking and some of your comments, it seems like you may be confusing database state changes with dyno state changes. Dynos (representing the servers for your application runtime), are restarted [once per 24 hours roughly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) and these servers are ephemeral. Thus the memory is blown away. The 'roughly' part accounts for fuzzing so that all of your dynos aren't restarting at the same time which would cause availability issues.

I don't think you actually need a webhook here. Conveniently, shortly before a dyno is due to be cycled (and blow away your memory) it will receive a [SIGTERM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown) and be given 30 seconds to clean up after itself. That `SIGTERM` can be trapped and you can then save your data to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't yet have a setup where I can scale my service at all, I'll need to route the requests for this to work but this is not yet my priority.

Yes I also wanted to investigate reboots and SIGTERM looks promising thing to use for daily ones.

And last two months I received about 3 emails that signalled that DB is read only. So I wanted to eventually solve that too. And currently I don't know how to recover from read-only DB yet.